# get value separately from json object in java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlet-3.0

this is my javascript code to send json object to servlet

```
username = "Nash";
password = "619here";
type = "all";
data = '{ "username": "' + username + '", "password": "' + password + '", "type": "' + type + '" }';
request = JSON.parse(data);

$.getJSON(url, request, function (response) {
    $("#result").append("<h1>Success</h1>");
    $.each(response.vehicle, function (no, vehicle) {

        $.each(vehicle, function (key, value) {

            $("#result").append("<h2>" + key + " : " + value + "</h2>");

        });

        $("#result").append("<br>");
    });

})
```

I want read json object from java servlet and get data separately. like this

```
String username = username from json object
String password = password from json object
String type = type from json object
```

I'm using json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your servlet, do the following in the `do[Get,Post]()` method

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject( request.getQueryString() );  

String username= jsonObject.get( "username" );  
String password= jsonObject.get( "password" ); 
String type= jsonObject.get( "type" );
```

You also need the remove the following line from your JS.

```
request = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: it gives this exception..  
net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of callback=jQuery19009972247087862343_1370721676614&username=Nash&password=619here&type=all&_=1370721676615