# ajax calling the wrong servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

weird problem here I can't seem to solve.

I'm working in Eclipse Java EE, I have a servlet called Process (mapped to /process)

There is a link to process

```
<a href="process?intent=order">Checkout</a>
```

Within process is a doGet method, verifying there is a user logged in, which redirects to a checkout page. (this works) The checkout page contains items, each with an individual input, and I have a seperate doPost method which updates the DB.. obtaining the input to update as follows

```
<input id='ID created in servlet' value='decided in servlet'>
```

followed by

```
<button id="update">Button</button>
```

I have the following JS

```
  var json = [];
  $('#update').click(function(){
   $('.items').find('input').each(function(){
     var tmp = "{id:" + $(this).attr('id') + ",quantity:" + $(this).val() + "}";
     json.push(tmp);
   });

    $.ajax( {
     url : 'process',
     type : 'POST',
     data : json,
     dataType : 'json',
     success: function(data) {
             alert("success");
     }
 });

});
```

So, two questions I guess.

First, this is sending a request to a different servlet, in a different project. However when accessed using a doGet, it works. (I have different code for a doPost) Is there any reason it's not recognizing the doPost method within my Process.java file? What could cause it to search for another servlet?

Second, I know what to do once I get the data in the servlet, but I don't know how to actually access the data. It's passed through jquery in 'data:', then how would I access it in the servlet?

Comment: Is your javascript code in another file in a different path?

Comment: I tried url:'projectName/process' to no avail. It still calls process in the other project. @AlexandreLavoie The js is in <script> tags within MyProject/jsp/page.jsp.. ajax calls through the URL I thought, would that matter how my file structure is?

Comment: What Aman is telling, is that you are using relative path, so the call is relative to the current URL. You can change `url : 'process'` by `url : '/your-context-path/process'` and replace with the right path.

Comment: What is the name of the project ? The name which you gave in Eclipse ?Read through the answer which i have just posted. It should help i guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question:**
If i have understood right, Your problem is that "when you try to send a post request using AJAX (inside a jquery function), you are not hitting the desired servlet".
**Solution:**
 You need to append the name of your project to the url.
So lets say your servlet is placed in project named `"SomeProject"` and the servlet is mapped to  url named `"servletProcess"`. 
So your jQuery should look something like this:

```
var json = [];
  $('#update').click(function(){
   $('.items').find('input').each(function(){
     var tmp = "{id:" + $(this).attr('id') + ",quantity:" + $(this).val() + "}";
     json.push(tmp);
   });

$.ajax( {
 url : '/SomeProject/servletProcess',
 type : 'POST',
 data : json,
 dataType : 'json',
 success: function(data) {
         alert("success");
 }

  });

});
```

This should fix the problem :)  
**Second Question:** try this [Similar Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002805/get-value-separately-from-json-object-in-java-servlet)

Comment: It did! It's always the simplest things. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is, as soon as I used url:'/MyProject/process' it worked. What's weird is I tried that before, but it didn't work. I exited all other projects that were currently synchronized under the server, tried again and it still reloaded the foreign servlet. So I changed the URL to what you suggested and it worked. Thanks again! I'd upvote if I could!!